# Nice GeoPath junctions in GeoGraphics

Tags: output-formatting, geographics

The two lines:

```
coords = {{10, 10}, {10, 20}, {20, 20}, {20, 10}};
GeoGraphics[{Thickness[0.05], GeoPath[coords]}]
```

return

[image]

You can see that the junctions (top right and bottom right) are not smooth. In [`GeoPath documentation`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeoPath.html), it is written that

> Joining of line segments can be specified using [`JoinForm`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/JoinForm.html).

However, `GeoGraphics[{JoinForm["Round"], Thickness[0.05], GeoPath[coords]}]` returns the same output.

Any idea on how to obtain nice junctions?

It can be really ugly when joining a lot of coordinates:

```
coords = Table[{Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {t, 0, Pi, Pi/20.}];
GeoGraphics[{JoinForm["Round"], Thickness[0.1], GeoPath[coords]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

As a workaround, break the path into multiple overlapping paths using [`Partition`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Partition.html) and use [`CapForm`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CapForm.html)

```
coords = {{10, 10}, {10, 20}, {20, 20}, {20, 10}};

GeoGraphics[{Thickness[0.05], CapForm["Round"],
  GeoPath[Partition[coords, 2, 1]]}]
```

[image]

```
coords = Table[{Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {t, 0, Pi, Pi/20.}];

GeoGraphics[{CapForm["Round"], Thickness[0.1],
  GeoPath[Partition[coords, 2, 1]]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the workaround. Do you think it's a bug?

Comment: It is at a minimum annoying. Report it to Wolfram and see if they say that it's a feature.